# Email throttling in ExactTarget

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I'm sending emails to large subscriber lists so I'm throttling the send in ExactTarget. I'm wondering how carefully I need to calculate the throttle rate.

For example, if I'm sending to 50,000 recipients at a time and I want to throttle the send at 5000 per hour. Let's say I only select the time frame to be from 2-6pm, so it will send 20,000 emails in that time. What happens to the rest of the 30,000 recipients? Do they not get the email or will the emails be sent in a huge batch after 6pm?

Additionally, what happens if I choose 'No Limit' for the throttle limit? Will ExactTarget more or less evenly spread the 50,000 recipients from 2-6pm and finish the send by 6pm?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late now and you already know the answer but here are my thoughts:
For the first part of your question, the remaining 30000 will receive the following day between 2-6 pm

If there's no limit set, ET will send the max allowed within the time period and rest the following day at the same time. Not sure what the max limit is??

Please see these articles:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214182&type=1

https://sfdcleo.wordpress.com/2017/10/15/send-throttling-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud/